# Inserting date formula in excel getting #name? error after inserting with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel-formula

```
  for i,cellObj in enumerate(sheet_formula['R'],1):
       cellObj.value='= days($AG$1,C{0})'.format(i)
       sheet_formula.cell(row=1, column=18).value = 'Days Since'
```

using this concept to enter the excel formula  in excel 
after entering excel formula in excel i am getting "#NAME?" in excel column i don't know where i am doing wrong

Comment: Write it in *Excel* and lookup in `openpyxl`. Compare the diff to see how it have to be written.

Comment: hey thanks for you help i tried that thing but it is still not working any other way

Comment: hey any help in this still struggling

Comment: See [using-formulae](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae), last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

open-pyxl does not work with some of the excel  function. add the full name as such:

= days($AG$1,C{0})'.format(i)
change to = _xlfn.days($AG$1,C{0})'.format(i)
And it will be working correctly.

If you’re trying to use a formula that isn’t known this could be because you’re using a formula that was not included in the initial specification. Such formulae must be prefixed with xlfn. to work.

To check if a formula is included you can use:

from openpyxl.utils import FORMULAE

print "DAYS" in FORMULAE
if it false then _xlfn prefixed before the function